# Powershell Get all files and just one folder

Tags: powershell

I have on e diretory like this in a remote server:

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       15-04-2014     14:44                custerr
d-----       31-10-2014     16:04                ftproot
d-----       07-01-2019     12:02                history
d-----       31-10-2014     11:36                logs
d-----       05-08-2014     16:50                mailroot
d-----       15-04-2014     14:45                temp
d-----       05-05-2017     15:09                wwwroot
-a----       14-03-2018     14:42          14524 cdbase.asp
-a----       17-10-2017     14:49          14186 cdbase.asp.bak
-a----       25-11-2014     12:39          11150 cdbase.asp~
-a----       23-08-2018     15:04             91 cienciaVitaeConf.asp
-a----       26-01-2017     17:26           7459 functions.asp

and i need to get only the files of inetpub(parent) and files diretory wwwroot

d-----       05-05-2017     15:09                wwwroot > all files inside
-a----       14-03-2018     14:42          14524 cdbase.asp
-a----       17-10-2017     14:49          14186 cdbase.asp.bak
-a----       25-11-2014     12:39          11150 cdbase.asp~
-a----       02-03-2016     16:06          13630 cdbase_TESTES.asp
-a----       23-08-2018     15:04             91 cionf.asp
-a----       26-01-2017     17:26           7459 functions.asp

Missing something in my code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\SIGQUAL\inetpub -File -Include wwwroot  |  Select-String  -Pattern '192.*'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do two queries:

```
@(
    Get-ChildItem -Path \\SIGQUAL\inetpub\wwwroot -File
    Get-ChildItem -Path \\SIGQUAL\inetpub -File
) | Select-String  -Pattern '192.*'
```

Comment: Hi Mathias! Thanks again for your quick help! Works perfectly.